# KDE - Allow focus stealing only when launching app

Tags: kubuntu, kde

Is it possible to tell KDE to allow windows to steal focus only upon launch?

I want a window to be brought to top if I just created it, for example if I just launched a program, or pressed `ctrl+alt+t` to open the terminal.

However, I want to prevent all focus stealing from already open apps.